# Merely using the (installed) pdfpages package causes a compiling error. Any suggestions?

Tags: pdfpages

I'm trying to use the `pdfpages` package in an article, but even compiling it with `\usepackage{pdfpages}` in the preamble produces the following error messages...

> Undefined control sequence. }
>
> Missing \begin{document}. }
>
> Undefined control sequence. }
>
> Undefined control sequence. }
>
> Undefined control sequence. }
>
> You have requested release '2020-10-01' of LaTeX, but only release '2020-02-02' is available.
>
> Overfull \hbox (110.47952pt too wide) in paragraph
>
> Underfull \vbox (badness 1742) has occurred while \output is active []
>
> Underfull \vbox (badness 4229) has occurred while \output is active []

...the first five of which relate to the `eso-pic.sty` package, line 188 (for some reason). Needless to say, the `\includepdf` command doesn't work either.

I have updated packages in the MiKTeX console (single user installation only) and the `pdfpages` package is definitely installed. I'm at the end of my tether here, as I need to get this done promptly; any help you can offer, therefore, would be greatly appreciated.

Incidentally, I'm using an updated version of TeXStudio and the article already has three images generated by the `graphicx` package contained within (not sure if that's relevant, but can't hurt to report).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you provide a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/201628) that reproduces these errors? Without an example one can only guess where the errors come from, so it will be hard to be really helpful.

Comment: eso-pic requires a new latex, but you seem not have updated latex too.

Comment: How do I go about updating Latex, Ulrike? The Miktex console doesn't appear to offer that functionality. And when I go to Miktex.org and download the installer it won't let me overwrite my existing installation!

Comment: well latex is updated in the same way as other packages. show a screenshot of the package list if you search for latex.

Comment: I had the exact same problem (line 188 of eso-pic.sty) and had to uninstall MikTex and reinstall a new version.

Answer (score 1):

I am not an expert. But here is what I did to fix this issue:

1. Go to the Miktex console, "updates" on the left, "check for
   updates", and updates everything I can.
2. "Packages" on the left,
   search for "pdfpages", delete it and reinstall it.

Note that you need to "run as an administrator" in the miktex console. And finally, restart the miktex for the updates to work.